# prerequisites for composer operation

Tags: php, composer-php

When doing a `composer update` for a specific `composer.json`, is it possible to define/override certain environment conditions and prerequesites, e.g. the PHP version, operating system or specific packages being present (when in reality they are not)?

I know that you can do these things with a custom composer plugin using `Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface`, but is that by any chance also possible with pure configuration?

The goal here is to generate a `composer.lock` file, that would then be used somewhere else (where the platform environment is different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence this by using the `config.platform` section in the `composer.json` file. Details can be found here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

Comment: thx, that was what I was looking for regarding the platform requirements. However, is it also possible to define a requirement in the `composer.json` as a metapackage, so that it does not actually get installed, when doing `composer update` (or later with `composer install` when using the `composer.lock` file).